# Looking for a generic `bisect` function

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a `bisect` operation in Haskell similar to Python's `bisect_left()` and friends.  The input would be a lower bound, an upper bound, a non-decreasing function (Ord a)=>(Int->a) which must be defined for all integers between the lower and upper bound, and a search value.  The return value is the highest integer `i` where `lower <= i <= upper` and `f(i) < search_term`.  Performance should be O(log(n)).

Hoogling for this:

```
(Ord a)=>(Int->a)->Int->Int->a->Int
```

does not yield any results.

Is there a standard, generic binary search operator in a library somewhere?

Comment: Is the `Int -> a` function assumed to be monotonically increasing/nondecreasing?

Comment: @jwodder the function should be non-decreasing -- edited to add the constraint

Comment: You may also like finger trees, which are designed to have an efficient search for monotonic predicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ross Paterson's [binary-search](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-search) package on Hackage does what you're looking for. Specifically, see [searchFromTo](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary-search/0.0/doc/html/Numeric-Search-Range.html#v:searchFromTo), which has type signature

```
searchFromTo :: Integral a => (a -> Bool) -> a -> a -> Maybe a
```

As Tikhon points out, `[a]` in Haskell is a *linked list* rather than an array. Since linked lists only support sequential access, it is not possible to get a logarithmic-time search on an `[a]` data structure. Instead, you should use a genuine array data structure -- see the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) library for the preferred implementation of arrays.

Dan Doel has written a family of binary search functions for the *mutable* vectors in the vector package: see [Data.Vector.Algorithms.Search](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-algorithms/0.5.4/doc/html/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Search.html) in his [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) library. In contrast to Ross Paterson's library, which provides a pure API, the API in `Data.Vector.Algorithms.Search` is monadic (that is, it must be run in the `ST` monad or the `IO` monad).

Answer (score 3):

A function like `bisect_left` (assuming I read its documentation correctly) cannot really exists for lists.

This makes sense--since you don't have random access in O(1) in lists (remember that Haskell lists are *linked lists*, while Python uses something more like a vector), you could not really get an O(logn) binary search.

Particularly, just getting to the middle of the list takes O(n/2) (which is just O(n)) steps, so an algorithm that involved the middle of the list (like binary search) would have to be in Ω(n).

In short--binary search does not make sense on *lists*. If you're doing a lot of searching, you probably want a different data structure. Particularly, take a look at `Data.Set` which uses binary trees internally.

Comment: @monadic But his type signature said list. His terminology is confused.

Comment: @bitbucket Indeed -- too much C programming makes me associate [] with the word "array", and I was sloppy.  However, what I'm really looking for is a binary search that works with *any non-decreasing function*, not just with a sorted List or Array.  So I edited out the sentences about Lists / Arrays because they just confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
binary_search :: Ord a, Integral b => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> a -> b
binary_search f low hi a = go low hi
     where
        go low hi | low + 1 == hi = low
        go low hi = go low' hi'
           where
              mid = (low + hi) `div` 2
              (low',hi') = if f mid < a then (mid,hi) else (low, mid)
```

(This may have an off-by-one error.)